# Hosting a runnable jar file (Discord bot) on a web server (Heroku)

Tags: java, heroku

I just finished creating a simple Discord bot in a runnable jar. (As a disclaimer, when it comes to the web, I'm a noob.) I was looking for a way to freely run it online and I read about all these VPS sites, but none of them offered unlimited free plans. So I stumbled into a site called Heroku, which allows me to run it for a good portion of the month. I've mostly figured everything out, but there is this one error that I've been unable to fix:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
```

My Discord bot does not connect to Heroku's server and I think thats the problem, but I have no clue how to fix it. Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Am I going about hosting my bot the right way? Thanks.

Edit: Here is the full logs:

```
2016-06-11T17:00:56.792783+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:00:56.792 [main] DEBUG d.btobastian.javacord.ImplDiscordAPI - Requested gateway wss://gateway.discord.gg (token: **************************************************NdxxxW0oQ)
2016-06-11T17:00:56.765456+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:00:56.765 [main] DEBUG d.btobastian.javacord.ImplDiscordAPI - Requesting gateway (token: **************************************************NdxxxW0oQ)
2016-06-11T17:00:57.199263+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:00:57.199 [ReadingThread] DEBUG d.b.j.utils.DiscordWebsocketAdapter - Sending connect packet
2016-06-11T17:00:57.267527+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:00:57.267 [ReadingThread] DEBUG d.b.j.utils.DiscordWebsocketAdapter - Received READY-packet!
2016-06-11T17:00:57.270636+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:00:57.270 [ReadingThread] DEBUG d.b.j.utils.DiscordWebsocketAdapter - Updating status (game: none, idle: false)
2016-06-11T17:01:38.508359+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:01:38.507 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG d.b.j.utils.DiscordWebsocketAdapter - Sending heartbeat (interval: 41250)
2016-06-11T17:02:19.751552+00:00 app[web.1]: 17:02:19.751 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG d.b.j.utils.DiscordWebsocketAdapter - Sending heartbeat (interval: 41250)
2016-06-11T17:02:22.866430+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2016-06-11T17:02:23.649874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

So my application does not actually interact with the Heroku server and it "times out" appartently. When I run it locally, all is well, but when I upload it to a Heroku application, it "times out." I've looked for ways to bind the $PORT but been unsuccessful so far. I've inluded it in my Procfile with no results:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar ideaprojects.jar --host=0.0.0.0 --port=$PORT
```

I've never interacted with ports before, can someone help me out? Thanks again.

Edit2: I even tried to run my bot through their "java-getting-started" by adding my Java code to the end of theirs. Heroku doesn't crash, but it seems that my bot doesn't run either.

Comment: Do you have any server logs that could help with troubleshooting this?

Comment: Is dropbox or google drive not an option? Also you can maybe use torrents to host the file

Comment: Show the contents of your `Procfile`. You are probably not binding to the $PORT

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because your `Procfile` configured as **web**. You need to configure `Procfile` as **worker** process.

You can try this `Procfile` configuration:  `worker: java -jar target/*.jar`

Also you can to look this page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/run-non-web-java-processes-on-heroku

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is for hosting web applications. It is not intended for hosting processes that aren't part of a web application you're running on Heroku, and trying to run such a process will not work well.

You will need a VPS to host your bot. Yes, you have to pay for this.